# Unable to secure webapi with Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a .NET Core 2.1 project with Identity Server and ASP.NET Identity. Everything seems to work fine except for one custom endpoint I have added. I have followed this: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/add_apis.html

I get a token from `/connect/token` and the UserInfo endpoint returns the right user. But when I query my custom endpoint I get the error: 
`IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration;`

The site is hosted in Azure and I don't get this error on my local. I have read some solutions regarding the certificate but I have added a self-signed certificate to Azure and it's still not working.

The openid-configuration endpoint is working ok with Postman.

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Azure probably kicking out a HTTP request.  Have you tried changing everything to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Everything was working under HTTPS. The issue was happening when the WebApi was querying ID server and as @DalmTo said it was kicking out the connection. This was happening because Azure by default is not configured to send http requests using TLS 1.2. Once I configured it it worked perfectly. What I cannot understand is why TLS 1.2 requests is not the default on Azure when it is to accept those requests.